# google vision api "We can not access the URL currently."

Tags: google-cloud-vision

An error occurs when the image address is a domain.
But it succeeds when it's IP.

error - http://clickoneq.com/test.jpg
success - http://220.95.232.99/test.jpg

https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate

request content:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "http://clickoneq.com/test.jpg"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

response content:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 8,
        "message": "We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

domain = error
IP = success

http://220.95.232.99/test.jpg

request content:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "http://220.95.232.99/test.jpg"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

responses SUCCESS